# Metro Style RichTextBox Control Enable URL Detection?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, richtextbox, lynx

## The Problem

In the .NET Framework, it would just be a matter of setting a property true and hooking to the link clicked event. But how would I do this in WinRT using the limited .NET framework.

## Why Is This Necessary?

Well I want to create a text based web browser (like Lynx but with a GUI), that is designed with people who don't want to use a fancy web browser or just need accessibility. Some of the features would be to display the URLs for instance 'http://stackoverflow.com/' to a URL in which I hookup the link clicked event and then redirect within the program and display the text.

## Conclusion

Requesting the HTML and converting it to text, was simple, and I already have it done and working fine. So the only thing I need from the Stack Overflow community. Is whether the RichTextBox support hyper-links? and how can it be done? No code examples necessary, but pointers will just do. I have already done research, but Metro Style applications are just fresh out of the oven; not a lot of articles out there.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows-8 App style way of doing this is to put a button inside an `InlineUIContainer` inside a textblock.

See [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/1d162d99-84a9-48f0-a8ef-dd770ced90c8) for some related discussion.